# Which group is this?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Define $G=\left\langle a,b\ |\ a^2=1, (ab^2)^2=1 \right\rangle $.

This is an infinite group whose Cayley graph is best described as a two-dimensional grid. Is it a well-known group? What is known about its main properties?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking if the group has a more common name? Because looking at this, the group just is what it is. It is the group having generators $a$ and $b$ which interact in the way given in the notation.

Comment: Yes, either that or it would be just good to know any nice properties that it has. Perhaps it's been researched by someone.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Hmmm... I am not an algebrist but I know a little. I'll play around with it and see what happens. No promises, though.

Comment: Thanks. If you play around with it and discover something, it would be nice to share our findings :)

Comment: Care to explain with respect to which generating set the Cayley graph is a two-dimensional grid? (I'm not seeing it, since the relation $(ab^2)^2=1$ suggests a 6-cycle, which is not something I would expect to see in what is commonly referred to as a two-dimensional grid.) The most famous group whose Cayley graph is a two-dimensional grid is $\mathbb Z^2$ under addition, with generating set $\{(\pm 1,0),(0,\pm 1)\}$.

Comment: Isn't the group _"too free"_ to be represented by a 2D grid of any sort? It seems to have an exponential growth rate.

Answer (score 5):

You can rewrite the second relation to give the alternative presentation
$$\langle a,b \mid a^2=1, a^{-1}b^2a=b^{-2} \rangle$$
which is an HNN extension, so you can derive its properties, such as normal form for group elements,  from the known properties of HNN-extensions.

I don't know whether it has a better known `name', but it is the quotient group of the Baumslag-Solitar group ${\rm BS}(2,-2) = \langle x,y \mid x^{-1}y^2x = y^{-2} \rangle$ by its centre $\langle x^2 \rangle$.

It is automatic, but not hyperbolic, because it has the free abelian subgroup $\langle (ab)^2,b^2 \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the original poster is correct about this group having a Cayley Graph which can be nicely drawn on a grid. Excuse my MS Paint skills. Continue the diagram to infinity. Since $a$ has order $2$ we don't need an arrow, and $b$ has infinite order. Note that the relations hold. By drawing the Cayley Graph this way I do not think I have accidently introduced any new relations.

[image: CayleyGraph]

If one pretends the border of this graph wraps back around, one can construct various quotients. Doing so in the above picture we obtain a group of order $16$, SmallGroup(16,3) in GAP.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't have a name, I vote we call it the *running bond group*. Although that's kind of ambiguous as I don't think it's the symmetry *of* a running bond tiling, but I'm willing to live with that.